# Sails.js interaction between the rendered 'view' and the controller

Tags: controller, routes, sails.js

I'm trying to make a main page (a view rendered when 'GET /') where there is a form with one field that submits with POST to ('/') then the 'routes' will call a function from the controller that will check the database and if the value is already on the database I'll have some error message shown on the main page.

Can this be done?

The only method I've used is the one where you use 'res.redirect()' or 'res.view()' depending on the result of the query, but I'm trying not to render the main page again nor change the url.

Thank you for your time.

**Edit 1: trying @Royalist answer**
**Edit 2: starting to learn a bit of jQuery, changed some things**
**Edit 3: The controller is doing what it should do**
**Edit 4: Everything works now!**

**routes**

```
'GET /thing': {
controller: 'ThingController',
action: 'getThing'
},
'POST /thing': {
controller: 'ThingController',
action: 'postThing'
},
```

**controller**

```
getThing: function (req, res) {
    res.view('thing');
},

postThing: function (req, res) {
    console.log('Inside postThing');
    Thing.findOne({name: req.param('name')}).exec(function (err, thing) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({status: 3});/* Some nasty error */
        }
        if (!thing) {
            Thing.create({name: req.param('name')}).exec(function (err, createdThing) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Wrong data');
                    return res.json({status: 2});/* The data is not correct */
                }
                console.log('Everything ok');
                return res.json({status: 0});/* Created succesfully */
            });
        }
        if (thing) {
            console.log('Already exists');
            return res.json({status: 1});/* The thing already exists */
        }
    });
}
```

**view**

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function postThing(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/thing',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {name: $("#name").val()},
        success: function(res) {
          switch (res.status){
            case 0: {
              console.log('Created succesfully!');
              break;
            }
            case 1: {
              console.log('This thing already exists');
              break;
            }
            case 2: {
              console.log('What you are trying to insert is wrong');
              break;
            }
            case 3: {
              console.log('Boooom');
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="Javascript:postThing();" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Now everything works fine.
The only concern I have has to do with the security. I don't know if using ajax to post is secure or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.

Have your form trigger a Javascript method on submit. JQuery will do just fine:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'your/api/route/',
  data: {
      value: 'to server'
  },
  success: function(response) {
      /* Handle Response */
  }
});
```

Then, you will need to [setup the route](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes) which will handle the POST, as well as include jQuery or another Javascript library that supports AJAX. Finally, in the method you've associated with the route, perform whichever actions you need to on the database.

Comment: I could make it work using ajax, only a bit concerned about the security of this method.

Comment: I would be concerned about an unencrypted message, too. There are ways to implement policies in Sails that turn HTTP requests to HTTPS request. Good to look into.